# Description of Anderson-Putnam CW-complex construction

Tags: symbolic-dynamics, cw-complexes, discrete-dynamical-systems

I have been trying to read the paper, [Topological invariants fo substitution tiling and their associated $C^*$-algebras](https://www.cambridge.org/core/journals/ergodic-theory-and-dynamical-systems/article/topological-invariants-for-substitution-tilings-and-their-associated-castalgebras/5D7DB90543165287CA5C4CBF012323F5), to learn more about a construction of Anderson-Putnam complexes. However, it seems like the only place where the construction is given, is implicitly at the end of section 2, and examples for $1$-dimensional CW-complexes.

I am intersted to try and understand the general construction, even in the case of symbolic dynamics. I have seen this construction mentioned in many places, but I am just interested in understanding what it means first.

I would appreciate any help, and especially help about how such a $2$-dimensional complex would look like.

Comment: The construction is quite explicit. The 2-cells are the (collared) prototiles, and they are glued together on edges according to if those two tiles appear next to one another in a legal patch of the tiling. This produces a branched manifold. For 1 dimension, this is even easier. You just get a graph whose edges are the (collared) letters in your alphabet, and if an $a$-tile can be followed by a $b$-tile, then you glue the right end of the $a$-edge to the left end of the $b$-edge.